# How to specify output name of cc_binary target

Tags: bazel

I'd like to build a simple application and to specify its output name: for debug version 'd' prefix should be added. I tried to use `genrule` for it, but I don't know how to change this option in different compilation modes. However I suppose that using `genrule` is not correct way.

So, how to specify output name?

```
cc_binary(
    name = "TestApp",
    srcs = [
        "src/TestApp/main.cpp",
    ],
)

genrule(
    name = "output_name_rule",
    srcs = [":TestApp"],
    outs = ["TestAppd.exe"],
    output_to_bindir = True,
    cmd_bat = "rename $(location TestApp) TestAppd.exe"
    )

config_setting(
    name = "release_build",
    values = {
        "compilation_mode":"opt"
    }
)

config_setting(
    name = "debug_build",
    values = {
        "compilation_mode":"dbg"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[genrule.outs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule.outs) is documented as nonconfigurable, so you can't use it directly. I would create a genrule that copies the file that exists in all configurations, and then choose between the genrule and the original cc_binary based on the configuration. Something like this:

```py
genrule(
    name = "copy_with_d",
    srcs = [":TestApp"],
    outs = ["TestAppd.exe"],
    output_to_bindir = True,
    cmd_bat = "rename $(location TestApp) TestAppd.exe"
)

alias(
    name = "maybe_with_d",
    actual = select({
        ":debug_build": "TestAppd.exe",
        "//conditions:default": "TestApp.exe",
    }),
)
```

Some notes on things to tweak for your use case:

- On Linux, I would write `cmd = "cp $< $@"`. I'm not sure how Windows `rename` handles the input not being writable. You can definitely write `$<` and `$@` instead of repeating the filenames though, they are Bazel ["Make" variables](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/make-variables.html).
- I put the non-`d` version as `//conditions:default` so it applies in fastbuild too, up to you which way you want as the default.
- Up to you whether you use `TestApp.exe` or `:TestApp.exe` or `:TestApp` in `alias.actual` to refer to that version, they're all equivalent. Same with `TestAppd.exe` vs `copy_with_d` or `:copy_with_d`, etc.